# What will be the output of these two codes?

Tags: java, c

I am new to programming and while practicing some questions I came across a code in C.

```
void count(int n)
{
   static int d = 1;
   printf("%d ", n);
   printf("%d ", d);
   d++;
   if(n > 1) count(n-1);
   printf("%d ", d);
}
int main()
{
    count(3);
}

Output:
3 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 4
```

Can anyone explain me to that why the output is not 3 1 2 2 1 3 4 as I am expecting.
I tried writing this code in java and the output is not even close to my expectation

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    count(3);
}
static void count(int n){
    int d = 1;
    System.out.print(n+" ");
    System.out.print(d+" ");
    d++;
    if(n>1)count(n-1);
    System.out.print(d+" ");

}

Output:
3 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Is there anything I am missing about function and method calling procedure.

Comment: Why did you expect single `4` and not `4 4 4`? You invoked `count` 3 times and last `printf("%d ", d);` is always ensured since it belongs to that method and is not part of any conditional block. Regarding Java code example `d` is not static so it doesn't belong to class but is simply local variable so each time you call `count` method it will create its own `d`, initialize it with `1`, increment it and then print it at the end.

Comment: In the C code, if you follow it through with pencil and paper, you will see that the additional `4`s are printed at the exit of each recursion. Only after the recursive call `count(n-1);` does the second `printf("%d ", d);` happen, one after another

Comment: [It's Déjà vu all over again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281902/dont-use-compiler-c-program-output-explanation-needed-in-logic?noredirect=1#comment63982750_38281902). Shame that question was deleted. And your Java version isn't equivalent, as the variable `d` isn't static in that source, as it is in the C source.

Comment: Now I get it, I didn't know that the last printf will be printed at last as it was not part of any conditional block. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C` a `static` variable retains its value accross function calls.

With this in context, you can see what happens when `count(3)` is called.

```
count(3)
prints: 3 1

    count(2)
    prints: 2 2   

        count(1)
        prints: 1 3 4 

    count(2)
    prints: 4   

count(3)
prints: 4
```

You are missing the last two `4` because you are forgetting that:

```
once `count(1)` returns `count(2)` prints the value of `d` once more, and
once `count(2)` returns `count(3)` prints the value of `d` once more
```

Now, for your `java` code, it is not equivalent to the `C` code, because `d` is not a static member. You can make it similar to  your`C` code by making `d` a static member.

```
/* ... Some code ...*/
static int d = 1;
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    count(3);
}

static void count(int n){
// Remove this line
/*int d = 1;*/
/* ... same code ...*/
/* ... same code ...*/
}
```

This `java` code should give same result as your `C` code.

Comment: Well I think the problem is with static, I should start learning more about static variables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code does, line by line:

Declare void function count with single argument n

```
void count(int n)
{
```

Declare int d as `static`: this means it'll stay the same through function calls. If you increment a static variable, the function returns and the function gets called again, the static variable will stay incremented.

```
   static int d = 1;
```

Print the argument and the static variable d

```
   printf("%d ", n);
   printf("%d ", d);
```

Increment d (LOOK OUT: this means that if we call count() again, which we'll do in the next line, d will not be equal to 1, but to 2)

```
   d++;
```

If n is larger than 1, call count with n - 1 as argument

```
   if(n > 1) count(n-1);
```

Print d

```
   printf("%d ", d);
}
```

So, this is what it does:

- count() is called with n as 3
- n (3) is printed
- d (1) is printed
- d is incremented with 1, it is now 2
- n (3) is larger than 1
- count() is called with 2 as argument
- n (2) is printed
- d (2) is printed
- d (2) is incremented with 1, it is now 3
- n (2) is larger than 1
- count() is called with 1 as argument
- n (1) is printed
- d (3) is printed
- d is incremented with 1, it is now 4
- n is equal to one
- d (4) is printed
- As you may have noticed we called count() three times, and it did not have time to finish two times.
- The only statement left after checking if `n > 1` is printing d
- We have to do that twice now
- d (4) is printed
- d (4) is printed

Comment: thanks for explaining it to me line by line. I was thinking that since the previous two time the last printf didn't get executed as it was the part of the if statement. I didn't see that the printf was not part of the conditional block.

Answer (score 0):

as [weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) mentioned already in the comment the recursion cause this output. If you want your expectet result i think this should help for your c-code:

```
void count(int n) {

    static int d = 1;
    printf("%d ", n);
    printf("%d ", d);
    d++;
    if (n > 1)
    {
        count(n - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ", d);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
        count(3);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C method uses a static variable in a function, which cannot be done in Java. A static variable is initialized on the first call to the function and then only updated on later function calls. Java does not have a concept like this, however, the following would do the same:

```
private static int d=1;

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    count(3);
}

static void count(int n){
    System.out.print(n+" ");
    System.out.print(d+" ");
    d++;
    if(n>1)count(n-1);
    System.out.print(d+" ");

}
```